# Countdown from specific date from mysql

Tags: javascript, date, countdown

Well this is probably easy for you guys but i seriously cant make it work.

So What i would like to do is make a countdown based on the date from mysql and make it going down in live mode whithout the need to refresh.

Code:

```
<?php 
$date = strtotime($row_tournaments['date']);
$remaining = $date - time();
$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
$hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
$minutes_remaining = floor(($remaining % 3600) / 60);
$seconds_remaining = ($remaining % 60);
echo "<p>$days_remaining <span style='font-size:.3em;'>dias</span> $hours_remaining <span style='font-size:.3em;'>horas</span> $minutes_remaining <span style='font-size:.3em;'>minutos</span> $seconds_remaining <span style='font-size:.3em;'>segundos</span></p>";
?>
```

This works fine but i need to refresh so i can see the time going down.

So i find this answer,

Code:

```
<p id="counter"></p>

<script>
var counter = new Date(2015,10,10,20,25,30);
var counterElem = document.getElementById("counter");
setInterval(function()
{
counter.setSeconds(counter.getSeconds() - 1);
counterElem.innerHTML = counter.getDate()+" <span style=\'font-size:.3em;\'>dias</span> "+counter.getHours()+" <span style=\'font-size:.3em;\'>horas</span> "+counter.getMinutes()+" <span style=\'font-size:.3em;\'>minutos</span> "+counter.getSeconds()+" <span style=\'font-size:.3em;\'>segundos</span>";
},1000);
</script>
```

that actually works pretty fine but the problem is that the

```
new Date(2015,10,10,20,25,30)
```

only accepts this format and in my database the format of the date is

```
2015-10-06 06:17:18
```

And i dont how to convert.

Please help, if you guys have a better solution is well welcome.

Thanks for your time.

Cumps.

All the code:

```
<div id="countdownContainer">
<a href="tournaments.php?id_tournament=<?php echo $row_tournaments['id_tournament']; ?>"><img src="images/wallpapers/<?php echo $row_tournaments['logo']; ?>.jpg"></a>
<div id="countdownContent">
<p>Próximo Torneio:</p>
<?php 
$date = strtotime($row_tournaments['date']);
$remaining = $date - time();
$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
$hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
$minutes_remaining = floor(($remaining % 3600) / 60);
$seconds_remaining = ($remaining % 60);
echo "<p>$days_remaining <span style='font-size:.3em;'>dias</span> $hours_remaining <span style='font-size:.3em;'>horas</span> $minutes_remaining <span style='font-size:.3em;'>minutos</span> $seconds_remaining <span style='font-size:.3em;'>segundos</span></p>";
?>


<p id="counter"></p>
<script>
str = "$row_tournaments['date']"; // Your db format  var date = new Date(Date.parse(str));
str = str.replace(/-/g,"/");
var counter = new Date(Date.parse(str));
var counterElem = document.getElementById("counter");
setInterval(function()
{
counter.setSeconds(counter.getSeconds() - 1);
counterElem.innerHTML = counter.getDate()+" <span style=\'font-size:.3em;\'>dias</span> "+counter.getHours()+" <span style=\'font-size:.3em;\'>horas</span> "+counter.getMinutes()+" <span style=\'font-size:.3em;\'>minutos</span> "+counter.getSeconds()+" <span style=\'font-size:.3em;\'>segundos</span>";
},1000);
</script>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: to convert your string from the DB use `var date = new Date(Date.parse("2015-10-06 06:17:18"));`

Comment: well i guees that can work but prob im doing something wrong, should i put the code like this var counter = new Date(Date.parse($row_tournaments['date']));? because if yes its not working the date doesnt show up.

Comment: @Saar that returns invalid date in some browsers because string isn't valid  format

Comment: any tips to make it work, i seriously cant think in anything. Cumps.

Comment: works for me. unless you gave wrong information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var str = "2015-10-06 06:17:18";  // Your db format
str = str.replace(/-/g,"/"); 
var date = new Date(Date.parse(str));
```

Here in second line I am replacing  delimiter - with / . This is because Date.parse() Expects delimiter as /

Comment: i do that and it counts well but when i change the date "2015-10-06 06:17:18" with my date from database $row_tournaments['date'] nothing shows up. Cumps.

Comment: Are you sure  $row_tournaments['date']   has value in it? May  be it is empty. print it and see if it has got value

Comment: Hey I got your problem. You need to sorround your variable within quotes like below
"$row_tournaments['date']"

Comment: yap theres a value inside when i do <?php echo $row_tournaments['date']; ?> it shows up.

Comment: So correct code would be 
var str = "$row_tournaments['date']";  // Your db format
str = str.replace(/-/g,"/"); 
var date = new Date(Date.parse(str));

Comment: the print i have is NaN dias NaN horas NaN minutos NaN  dont know why, cumps.

Comment: Please paste the javascript code. I want to see your code where you replaced  "2015-10-06 06:17:18" with your date from database $row_tournaments['date']. Because I suspect problem lies there

Comment: yeap theres probably problems in my main code ill paste it all up there, cumps. The code as been added.

Comment: I am not a PHP expert so asking.  using $row_tournaments['date'] inside script  tag is allowed in PHP?

Comment: well i actually dont know aswell

Comment: Try this
str = "<?php echo $row_tournaments['date'] ?>";

Comment: y it works but every time i refresh the page the countdown starts at the same point its not working properly like counting from today to that date. Theres problems in my code for sure if you could check the main code. If not its fine thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91244/discussion-between-dattatreya-kugve-and-bruno).